stability under holomorphic calculus
I have two questions:

I would like to know the exact meaning of "stability under holomorphic calculus" in the context of $C^*$-algebras
Is all unital noncommutative $C^*$--algebra stable under holomorphic calculus?


You have to provide more context than this. It’s not possible to tell you what this phrase means without you telling us where you have seen this phrase.

@DavidGao I saw it in this context: Let $A$ a C*-algebra and B a subalgebra stable under holomorphic calculus. I don't know if the author has used "stable" as a synonym of "closed" or there is a definition for "stable under holomorphic calculus". If my guess is correct, every C*-algebra would be closed under holomorphic calculus, right?

I cannot say for sure since you just provided one sentence, but it does sound like the author meant it as the subalgebra is closed under holomorphic functional calculus.

Yes, every $C^\ast$ algebra is closed under holomorphic functional calculus. If I had to guess, though, since the author didn’t say $B$ is a $C^\ast$-subalgebra, so the subalgebra in question may not be a $C^\ast$ algebra.

@DavidGao so, every C*-algebra would be closed under holomorphic functional calculus, right? sorry, I am new in the study of C*-algebras...

That is correct. In fact, every $C^\ast$ algebra is even closed under the more general notion of continuous functional calculus.
